# cross-frame scripting with <script src=.... to find status code of a site - Security issue?

Tags: javascript, security, scripting, dns, onerror

we have a site with Iframes pointing to dynamic Urls (by user input).
In case of a 404/500 or any other error, we want to replace the Iframe source with a different user friendly other URL.
For this we can use  with the onerror event to identify when the dynamic websites have problems.  (then, in case of problem replace the iframe url)
This works also for cross domain urls, however there might be a case where the dynamic url might be malicious and such security issue rises where the malicious code will execute in the same frame ,same domain of our website.

Is this assumption correct?
Is there any solution for this?
Any other suggestions?

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: The users can only specify the frame’s URL, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we have a site with Iframes pointing to dynamic Urls (by user input). In case of a 404/500 or any other error, we want to replace the Iframe source with a different user friendly other URL.

So it sounds like you are making a sort of "browser in a web page."

> For this we can use with the onerror event to identify when the dynamic websites have problems. (then, in case of problem replace the iframe url)

Yes, except not many things *have* onerror events. I assume you are aware of this from your comments on other answers. If I understand you right, you're talking about using a dummy `script` element to load the URL first (as a script, even though it's not really a script), and determine whether the URL is valid using the using `onload`/`onerror` handlers for the `script` element (`onerror` will not fire on a script error, only a network error).

> This works also for cross domain urls, however there might be a case where the dynamic url might be malicious and such security issue rises where the malicious code will execute in the same frame ,same domain of our website.
>
> Is this assumption correct?

Your assumption is correct. If the URL actually does contain a script, it will execute in the user's browser in the same domain as your site.

> Is there any solution for this?

A simple workaround might be to do something like what jsfiddle.net does... have a separate subdomain act as a "firewall" between the third-party content and your real domain.

> Any other suggestions?

The script preload hack is really just that, a hack. It misappropriates the script tag and makes needless requests. I would probably look into using XHR to fire off a HEAD request instead, or doing some light server-side proxying.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. as for the XHR- you mean by ajax head request? it will work only for same domain requests, correct?  i assume no other solution besides some proxying..

Comment: @Tal [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest), it can perform GET, POST, and HEAD requests

Comment: but how can i make this cross-domain?

Comment: @Tal if you can coordinate it with the owners of the other servers, you can use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), or if you can get your users to install a browser extension, you can do it that way. Otherwise a proxy is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use a `<script>` tag to embed a remote JS file, you have a security problem as the code is going to be executed in the context of your page.

The only workaround idea that comes to mind is making a server-side request to the resource and parse the response headers. This however may behave differently from a client-side request, as the call will be coming from the server, so it'll have a different IP, different cookies, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer- as for the 1st option - problem it doesnt work for cross-domain urls.   Server Side is ok, but we need also client side because of ips,proxys,etc.

Comment: @Tal of course, fixed, thanks. This becomes really difficult then...  JSONP isn't an option either, because it would execute a malicious response. Tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can only specify the frame’s URL, then any scripting in the frame’s document would be run in the context of the frame’s document and not in the context of the parent document the frame is embedded.

The question whether a script running inside the frame can access the parent’s document (i. e. your document) depends on the [origin of both documents](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy#General_Principles): only if they are equal both document’s are said to be *same origin*. And only in that case one document can access the other document.

Comment: Thanks Gumbo - but look at previous comments, we need to check whether the URL is accessible and working good. for that we thought using <Script src=url> in the parents frame - and in case of malicious url this would run in the parents frame.

Comment: But why do you think you need to do that? And how would you do that?

Comment: we want user to get a more friendly,configurable, message when there are problems with backend urls they use. so instead of getting the browser's 404/500/.. errors, they can get other message/configurabe html. for that we first (or in parallel) have a request to the url (by <script src=...>) and in parallel have an iframe the url. in case of error, we catch the onerror event and replace the iframe url.

Comment: But why do you want to use `script`?

Comment: Is there another option to access cross-domain urls? what other do you suggest?